# Enlightened badge - first overall answer or among those not deleted?

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

The definition of the Enlightened badge says:

> #### Enlightened
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Be the first person to answer a question, and receive a score of at least ten for that answer. The answer must be accepted by the question
>     owner, and [it mustn't be a
>     self-accept](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1156).

Does "the first" mean "the first including deleted answers" or just "the first among not deleted answers"?

Comment: Oh, so from what Grace Note marks as duplicate, it means the first among the not deleted.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess I should've mentioned that while closing. Oops.

Comment: @GraceNote I am thinking that this way one question can generate more than one Enlightened badge: if two answer and the 1st removes, then 2nd can get it once accepted and votes. After a while the 1st undeletes and gets enough votes and accepted --> gets the badge.

Comment: It's possible but it'd be really weird and contrived for this to happen if y'ask me. You'd need a question that not only can attract two (or more) 10+ vote answers, but they'd have to also have authors who would delete them and be to a question where someone would indeed change acceptance.